# What am I doing wrong? (Convertion)

Tags: python

I'm trying  to convert this meters to kilometers but I don't how to let the input to realize it's an integer

```
m = input("Enter the distance (meters) you want to convert to kilometers  ")
km =  1000
print (m/km,"km")
```

Comment: Can you give and example of input/output? Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I'm using 3 seems like my problem is already solve

Answer (score 2):

If you use Python 3 you can do this:

For taking `int`, you do this by `m = int(input("Enter int"))`

So, in your code just change `input()` to `int(input())`:

```
m = int(input("Enter the distance (meters) you want to convert to kilometers  "))
km =  1000
print (m/km,"km")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
m = int(input("Enter the distance you want to convert (meters) "))
km =  1000
print (m/km,"km")
```

Note the conversion of `m` from `str` to `int` using `int()`

Comment: Thanks a lot (I did this a while ago seems like I forgot the other 2nd end parenthesis)